# During git cherry-pick, undo changes to a single file, reverting to my version

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, git-cherry-pick, git-merge-conflict

I'm doing a `cherry-pick` for a large commit with multiple files. There are some conflicts, but for some of the conflicting files I'm sure that I don't need any of the changes. I'd just like to revert all changes applied to these files in that commit - a bit like 'resolve using mine' in svn, or `git checkout <filename>` to undo changes applied to a file (which doesn't seem to work here).

Is there a command to do this, without manually having to go through the diffs in these files?

FFR, feel free to also include the operation to resolve using *theirs*.

Comment: Try `git checkout <our-commit> -- <file>` to use ours, and `git checkout <their-commit> -- <file>` for theirs.

Comment: @ElpieKay that works perfectly, thanks! Do you want to post this as an answer so I can approve it?

Comment: @ElpieKay thanks, you should post this as the answer!

Comment: @ElpieKay this is answer material!